# Can someone explain this question.

Tags: general-topology

Let  $A$  be a proper subset of of $X$, $B$ be a proper subset of $Y$. If $X$ and $Y$ are connected, show that $(X\times Y)-(A\times B)$ is connected.

I have already seen the solution of this problem here on math.stackexchange, but my confusion is this. 
Suppose $X$=(a,b) & $Y$=(c,d) and let $A$={m} & $B$={n} be singleton sets such that $A\subset X$ & $B\subset Y$ then $(X\times Y)-(A\times B)$= $[(a,m)\cup(m,b)]\times[(c,n)\cup(n,d)]$ = $[(a,m)\times(c,n)]\cup[(m,b)\times(n,d)]$
which implies that  $(X\times Y)-(A\times B)$ is not connected.

Can someone explain me what I have done wrong & what is this question asking.

Comment: What is wrong is that your equation $(X\times Y)-(A\times B)$= $[(a,m)\cup(m,b)]\times[(c,n)\cup(n,d)]$ is not true. (Draw a picture...)

Comment: Thank You. I just realized my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

This is because $X\times Y-A\times B=[(a,m]\cup[m,b)]×[(c,n]\cup[n,d)]-${$(m,n)$}. For example take $X=Y=[-1,1]$ and $A=B=${$0$}. Then $X\times Y-A\times B$ is a square minus its center which is obviously connected while what you gained by calculations is the same square minus two lines that intersect in center of the square and are pairwise perpendicular to edges of it.

Answer (score 1):

Note that$$[(a,m)\cup(m,b)]\times[(c,n)\cup(n,d)]$$ is not the same  as $$ (X\times Y)-(A\times B).$$ Also note that $A\times B$ is a single point therefore  $ (X\times Y)-(A\times B)$ is connected.